# Are there Comparable alternatives to Java Servlets?

Tags: servlets

I understand that a servlet is an actual class in Java that basically extends and provides useful characteristics of a web server, but are there any alternative equivalents where the same similar key characteristics of a servlet are accomplished in a different language?

Particularly something that has:

- the servlet life cycle of `init()`, `service()` and `remove()`
- limitations on disk access (persistence)
- performing page layout function
- can be dynamically reloaded
- can call other servlets
- can operate like a URL
- similar security

I have found servlets in AJAX, Spring and the like, but I mean something that is not in the java family at all.   To specify further, I found the following but they don't seem to be used very much, both run over Java, and Armed Bear C-Lisp seems still employs a java virtual machine.

- [node-servlet](https://github.com/dschwen/node-servlet)
- [armed bear common lisp](http://abcl-web.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I tried, but couldn't find a proper info.

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a number of servlet alternative since servlet is just an implementation of HTTP request and response mechanism based on Java.

Almost all languages has a mechanism to deal with HTTP methods. They just not called 'servlet'. For example [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) has great tools for this. Have a look at [express.js](http://expressjs.com/) which is arguable most used node.js framework.

Make a google search like this: "x rest server" and use whatever language you want instead of 'x', you will most likely get what you asked for. Let's try it for a couple of languages:

```
ruby rest server : sinatra, grape
swift rest server : kitura, perfect, vapor
c# rest server : web api, servicestack 
javascript rest server : node.js, express.js, hapi.js
phyton rest server : django, flash
```